# convert org.jboss.netty.buffer.ChannelBuffer to String

Tags: java, byte

i want to convert ChannelBuffer buf = (ChannelBuffer) msg to String how to do that using java??

```
ChannelBuffer is org.jboss.netty.buffer.ChannelBuffer
```

Comment: From [javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/buffer/ChannelBuffer.html): *Various `toString(String)` methods convert a `ChannelBuffer` into a `String`. Please note that `toString()` is not a conversion method.*

Comment: Actually, all `toString(...)` methods containing a `String` in their signature are marked as `@Deprecated`. `toString(Charset)` or `toString(int, int, Charset)` should be used.

Comment: it gives me this LittleEndianHeapChannelBuffer(ridx=0, widx=70, cap=70)

Answer (score 2):

As documentation states

> Various [toString(String)](https://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/buffer/ChannelBuffer.html#toString(java.lang.String)) methods convert a ChannelBuffer into a String. Please note that toString() is not a conversion method.

Instead of calling `buf.toString()` you should do `buf.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` or other conversion method / encoding from the provided API.

Comment: @YoussefAssnai You tried what? Edit question and show what you tried. That way we *might* be able to identify why it's not working for you, i.e. what you did wrong.

Comment: @YoussefAssnai Please do elaborate on "doesn't work."

Comment: it gives me this LittleEndianHeapChannelBuffer(ridx=0, widx=70, cap=70)

Comment: i tried this : String converted = buf.toString(); it gives me LittleEndianHeapChannelBuffer(ridx=0, widx=70, cap=70)

Comment: That's because you're calling `buf.toString()`, read suggestion carefully - **Please note that toString() is not a conversion method.**

Comment: so what is the solution??

Comment: Take a look updates in the answer "Instead of calling `buf.toString()` you should do `buf.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` or other conversion method / encoding from the provided API. "

Comment: I tried that it gives me : MCGP ?: ?N$d ???   ????   ???   its not the expected result

Comment: Use different encoding then either one of [StandardCharsets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) or load with [Charset.forName](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#forName(java.lang.String))

Comment: I tried all methods of StandardCharsets it gave the same error

Comment: the expected result is:4d43475009803a2000080e5800370d3506d27693ff81ad8f032e240000a87d0cd4267e3c00b3b8f7827d3100b0f141817e3300b5169c817d0e007507dcda771d00870167b524

Comment: @YoussefAssnai provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want further assistance.